# what is this error about? ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308)

Tags: errors

When I run my latex i get this error for line 36. it is no matter what is in line 36. It just show this line with this error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ̈ (U+0308)
```

Comment: "line 36" can be line 36 is some other file. And you have an accent there, that pdflatex can't handle, perhaps from some copy&paste. Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0308}{HERE!HERE!}` to your document to find the problematic char.

Comment: Please provide more detail so we can adequately address your issue. Looking at your previous posts on this site, they have all been lacking enough context and rather just look like a "Here's some info, fix my problem" requests. Consider your audience and put some effort into improving your style of questioning. Could you do that?

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. Great suggestion. In my case, it was the character \¨{i} in bibliography that generated the issue. Substituting it with ï fixed it.